# XSL - Exclude some elements with position()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In my XML file, i have a list of external references like these

```
 <references>
     <reference id="ref1" ref-author="a"/>
     <reference id="ref2" ref-author="m"/>
     <reference id="ref3" ref-author="c"/>
  </references>
```

In this document, I have an element `citations` to associate to the wanted reference.

```
<cita ref="ref3"/>
```

The problem is, I only want it to transform the references that are referenced in the document. I want to number each reference, ordered by the author.
I've tried to use `position()` for this but, if some reference is not transformed, it will "count" anyway. So, if my second reference is missing, the others are displayed as [1] [3], instead of [1] [2] as expected.

This is my XSL for references:

```
<xsl:template match="references">
    <div class="references">
        <h2>References</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="reference">
            <xsl:sort select="@ref-author"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>      
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key use="@ref" name="listed-references" match="cita"></xsl:key>
<xsl:template match="reference">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="key('listed-references', @id)">
            <p>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                [<xsl:number value="position()"/>] <xsl:value-of select="@ref-author"/>, 
            </p>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to restrict the `position()` only to count the elements "reference" that will be transformed? Or there is another workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `xsl:apply-templates`. This will change the current node list which will allow `position()` to give you an accurate result.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <references>
        <reference id="ref1" ref-author="a"/>
        <reference id="ref2" ref-author="m"/>
        <reference id="ref3" ref-author="c"/>
    </references>
    <cita ref="ref3"/>
    <cita ref="ref2"/>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="references">
        <div class="references">
            <h2>References</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="reference[key('listed-references', @id)]">
                <xsl:sort select="@ref-author"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>      
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key use="@ref" name="listed-references" match="cita"/>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <p id="{@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',position(),'] ',@ref-author)"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">,</xsl:if>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<div class="references">
   <h2>References</h2>
   <p id="ref3">[1] c,</p>
   <p id="ref2">[2] m</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That results another problem. When the references are ordered by the author, the number appears unordered. It resulted in [2] [1], in the example i gave before